# With EF, does it make sense to learn DataSet

Tags: entity-framework, dataset

I'm doing some exercises on Data Access Layer in ASP.NET webforms. It looks to me as if everything I'm trying to do with DataSets, I can do with the Entity Framework. So today, does it make sense to learn DataSets? So many steps with DataSets just to get the same result as EF.

Comment: what if your next job is to fix legacy code that uses nothing but data sets? you will find your self out of favor

Comment: You are right, I have overlooked that aspect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you *need* to know how to ride a bicycle in order to drive a car? Nope. Does it *hurt* to know both? Nope.

If you're going to use EF you don't *need* to know datasets; EF is an abstraction built on top of traditional ADO.NET. At the same time, knowing how the underlying ADO connections/readers/etc work doesn't hurt, it helps you understand what is going on underneath.

However, knowing SQL Server, TSQL, and a bit (or more) about how the SQL optimizer works is more important than knowing ADO.NET if you're going to use EF (or any other OR mapper). Although much of that is also "hidden" by OR mappers it is still important to know what goes on "behind the scenes" to avoid making mistakes that can hurt performance etc.